# How to individually change text color and font weight in the same div element using Tailwind CSS and React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I want to have two text color and font-weight within the same text element like below.

```
                <div className={s.mainTitle}>
                    I want to keep this color white! <br />
                    But I want to only change the end word **green and bold**!
                </div>
```

In the above example, I want to change only `green and bold` to green/bold, i.e. apply `text-green-500` and `font-bold` using tailwind css.

In my current css file, I write something like

```
.mainTitle {
  @apply text-white-default
  @apply font-normal
}
```

How can I apply additional tailwind css properties only specific word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap a `<span>` tag around the text you want to style. A `<span>` tag is an inline element so it won't break the words inside of it on to a new line.

For example:

```html
<div className={s.mainTitle}>
    I want to keep this color white! <br />
    But I want to only change the end word <span className={s.greenAndBold}>green and bold</span>!
</div>
```

```css
.greenAndBold {
  @apply text-green-500
  @apply font-bold
}
```